# Sub-Users in Devise on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In reference to a previous question asked and answered: [sub-users-and-devise](http://https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/4379650/sub-users-and-devise) the OP was asking about how to have sub-users in devise. The answer given was to set up a `belongs_to has_many` relationship within the User model thus:

```
 class User
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'User'
  ...
 end
```

and modify the controller thus:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController  
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.parent_id = params[:parent_id] 
    respond_to do |format|
  end
  end
```

This would seem like a perfect solution to what I am trying to do, but I am having a hard time wrapping my mind around what migration one would need to make this work. I'm using Devise, my model and users table already exists, so I would need to actually generate a migration. Would it be as simple as adding a `parent_id` column to the `users` table? Wouldn't it be better to use an `add_reference` migration?

I tried this:

```
class AddUsersToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

but what I got was a `user_id` field, not a `parent_id` field, so any code, such as a view or a helper, that references `parent_id` gets an error

> undefined method `parent_id'.

Would someone help me to understand what migration is necessary to make this work?

Or is there a better way to go about setting up sub-users in Devise?

In case you need it, here are the relevant files in my app:

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for  :users, controllers: {
              :registrations => "users/registrations"
  }
...
end
```

Controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource
    resource.parent_id = params[:parent_id]
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'User', dependent: :destroy

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable
end
```

the helper that generates the error:

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=40&d=blank"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, class: "gravatar")
  end

  def current_user_is_head_of_household
    current_user.parent_id.nil?
  end

  def current_user_is_member_of_household
    !current_user.parent_id.nil?
  end
end
```

the view that calls `current_user_is_head_of_household`:

```
<h1>Lobby</h1>
<p>This is slated to be the jumping off point (home) where members can access the blog, training, personal information tracker and the various calculators.</p>

<% if current_user_is_head_of_household %>
  <%= link_to "Add user to your household", new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
```

and finally the error thrown:

> undefined method `parent_id' for #
>           Did you mean?  parent
>                          parent=
>
> ```
>     Extracted source (around line #11):
>
> 9
> 10      def current_user_is_head_of_household
> 11        current_user.parent_id.nil?
> 12      end
> 13    
> 14      def current_user_is_member_of_household
> ```

Comment: You posted the controller code under model. When dealing with recursive (or) tree structure I usually use wonderful [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem. I think you also need to whitelist the `parent_id` (it is [documented in Devise github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/#strong-parameters))

Comment: ooops...yes I did post controller code instead of model code...thanks for catching that.  I just fixed that in the post. 

Also thanks for the tip on the ancestry gem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migration to add parent reference & foreign-key

```
class AddParentToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :parent, index: true
    add_foreign_Key :users, :users, column: :parent_id
  end
end
```

User Model Associations

```
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'User', optional: true
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'User', foreign_key: :parent_id
```

Comment: Marked as accepted. Made the changes to my model and my migration as given and it worked for me. Also seeing it now has helped me to work it out in my head. Thanks Sikandar!

Comment: Happy to help :)